# Finding matching pairs in Excel table and creating new pair if it does not exist

Tags: excel

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAH25.png)

I am trying to match the pairs in columns G and H to any pairs in columns A and B. If there is no matching pair I want to create a new Integer Value ID (column C).

[image: Desired Product]

In the desired table, the pair(1,2.7) exists already in column A/B. But the pairs (2,2.9) and (3,3.4) do not so a new Integer Value ID should be created (ex 1009,1010)

I have tried  `match(1, (G2=A2:A10)*(H2=B2:B10),0)` to find matches. But I run into a circular reasoning error. Maybe I should use another table?

Comment: Are you open to use a helper column?

Comment: I am. It doesn't matter to me where all the data goes, I just want to make sure that every pair is accounted for, and there are no duplicates (i.e. the same pair creating two integer value IDs)

Comment: Does macro come into play?

Comment: I have not used macros in excel before

Comment: Would a macro be easier to use instead of trying to make it all happen with a formula?

Comment: @RyanCapule for sure! with a macro would be easier

Comment: `Copy/Paste` the 2nd table below the first.  `RemoveDuplicates`.  Continue the `Integer Value ID` column.  You can do this manually,  or by using VBA or Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

1. Use this array formula (press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in order to works correctly) in a helper column to determine if the pair of data already exists

> =IF(H2<>"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(G2=$A$2:$A$10)*(H2=$B$2:$B$10),0)),"",ROW()),"")

[image]

If the pair of data exists, the formula is showing the current row of the new data which has to be included on the original base.

2. Use the following formulas to add the new pair of data at the end of the original DB and drag down up to the row you want it:

> - Column A: =IFERROR(INDEX($G$1:$G$19,SMALL($I$1:$I$19,ROWS($A$10:A10))),"")
> - Column B: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$1:$H$19,SMALL($I$1:$I$19,ROWS($B$10:B10))),"")
> - Column C: =IF(B11<>"",C10+1,"")

And this is the final result:

[image]

[You can find an example here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZDEP5Gvzx9ptM79lwwXO3V4sclJkjeKc/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109997475435544900987&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: This looks great Mario! I have tried it in my excel worksheet, and I have one more question. Is there any way for the helper column I to notice duplicates in column G and H. I have extended the formula in columns A,B,C and I down and I would be putting more pairs in column G and H. For example, the pair (2,2.6) might come up again and I would not like it to create a new integer value ID since it already appeared once.

Comment: I am thinking that the formula in I should notice if the pair repeats in G/H because changing the formula to extend down to include the new additions in A/B cause circular reasoning.

Comment: @RyanCapule I have updated the example, please check it out and let me know if now is working as you expected.

Comment: It does! Thank you for your help. I appreciate it